# How to configure bower in Asp.net project using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, asp.net-core-2.0

I create an empty project using Visual Studio Code's terminal. Then I add bower.json and bower_config.bowerrc files then using terminal run the `bower update` command. The files contains next code:

bower.json

```
{
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"
    }
}
```

bower_config.bowerrc

```
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

But even I configured it to download files into `wwwrooot/lib` folder it still install into `bower_comoponents` folder. How can I resolve that?

P.S. I need to use Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bower configuration file should be named `.bowerrc` (no `bower_config` prefix).